# How to completely disable source code editing in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);` in the wp-config.php source code. Can admins still edit the source code by installing a file manager plugin?

If so, is there a way to completely disable this option without needing to disable plugin installation?

Comment: DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT prevents editing trough the wp feature. Installing 3rd party has nothing to do with this unless the author of the plugin is doing a check.